# Why Observable in Java use Vector?

Tags: java

From the SDK

```
public class Observable {
    private boolean changed = false;
    private Vector obs;

    /** Construct an Observable with zero Observers. */

    public Observable() {
    obs = new Vector();
    }
```

What is the main reason for using `Vector` instead of more type-safe collection such as `List<Observer>`?

Comment: I guess it's just because it's an old code. Generics came in 1.6.

Comment: @JanDvorak 1.5 (before even C# had them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a very old class, dating back to JDK 1.0. At the time, there was no `List`.

Comment: " dating back to JDK 1.0 " -- can you share your references?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Sure: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html (Since: JDK1.0).

Comment: I see. So is there any alternative to this class? or we have to roll our own version.

Comment: The `List` interface (no generics) was added in 1.2

Comment: @Chan what do you mean by alternative? The `Observable` interface should be type safe since it works by adding/deleting `Observer`s

Comment: Just found `Observable<T>` in the Android SDK ;). @aromero: I just don't like the Vector container :(.

Comment: @Chan You're avoiding `Observable` because it internally uses a class you don't like?

Comment: and just to mention it... Vector is synchronised, and the Collection classes (including List) are not!

Comment: @fazhool `List` is an interface

Comment: @SteveKuo yes, List is an Inteface... but any of it's implementing classes are still not thread safe, so by referring to List I actually meant one of the concrete classes.

Comment: @fazhool `Vector` is a `List` implementation, which is thread safe, and so is `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

Comment: @steveKuo I stand corrected... has anyone looked into the speed of CopyOnWriteArrayList vs. the old Vector? (while we are at it)... or any other comparison between those two? (doesn't the API state it's too costly).